# Google Drive file insertion error quotaExceeded

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Sometimes when I try to insert a file into a folder, I get this response

```
{
"code": 403,
"errors": [
{
"domain": "usageLimits",
"message": "The user has exceeded their Drive storage quota",
"reason": "quotaExceeded"
}
],
"message": "The user has exceeded their Drive storage quota"
}
```

What is "quotaExceeded"? Where can I get a list of all errors and their meanings of Google Drive API?

Answer (score 0):

List of errors with advice on how to handle them: https://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors

If you have exceeded your quota you can request more here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dG0wOFJPeVRxSUxuMHUzdlZpTkU4Z0E6MQ

Comment: I've seen this link, but it does not describe anything close to what I had (usageLimits, quotaExceeded)

Comment: what concerns the quota, this is the case because my app just started and I have a very small amount of requests